# MySQL 5.7.17 restarts unexpected

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Our mysql server service restarts once a day with the following error message:

> 2017-01-13T17:00:32.747103Z 1171090 [Note] Aborted connection 1171090
>   to db: 'someschema' user: 'someuser' host: 'someserver.com' (Got an
>   error reading communication packets) terminate called after throwing
>   an instance of 'std::out_of_range'   what():  vector::_M_range_check:
>   __n (which is 4294967295) >= this->size() (which is 0) 17:01:17 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ; This could be because you hit a bug. It is also
>   possible that this binary or one of the libraries it was linked
>   against is corrupt, improperly built, or misconfigured. This error can
>   also be caused by malfunctioning hardware. Attempting to collect some
>   information that could help diagnose the problem. As this is a crash
>   and something is definitely wrong, the information collection process
>   might fail.
>
> key_buffer_size=8388608 read_buffer_size=131072
>   max_used_connections=916 max_threads=1500 thread_count=612
>   connection_count=612 It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
>   key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
>   604207 K  bytes of memory Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some
>   variables in the equation.
>
> Thread pointer: 0x0 Attempting backtrace. You can use the following
>   information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no messages
>   after this, something went terribly wrong... stack_bottom = 0
>   thread_stack 0x30000
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0xe7fdcc]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x459)[0x7a9d39]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xf8d0)[0x7f81f88d58d0]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x7f81f72de067]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x7f81f72df448]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x15d)[0x7f81f7bcbb3d]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5ebb6)[0x7f81f7bc9bb6]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5ec01)[0x7f81f7bc9c01]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5ee19)[0x7f81f7bc9e19]
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz+0x11f)[0x7f81f7c1fcdf]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x11ae3fe] /usr/sbin/mysqld[0x11b0948]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z17dict_stats_updateP12dict_table_t23dict_stats_upd_option_t+0x1140)[0x11b4340]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(dict_stats_thread+0x331)[0x11b61c1]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x80a4)[0x7f81f88ce0a4]
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f81f739162d] The manual
>   page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
>   information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.

Running on Debian 8. MySQL Version 5.7.17 from oracle APT repository.
Couldnt find this issue inside the MySQL Bug Tracker for Version 5.7.17 nor 5.7.18 target version. Also the manual from Oracle wasnt helpful.

Comment: We got a similar stack trace with 5.6.35 and MySQL confirmed that they see something similar internally...
See also: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84940
If our conclusion is correct it is a problem introduced in 5.6.35/5.7.17 and you have either to wait for the next release where it is fixed or to downgrade to the previous release.
Greetings from shinguz from FromDual

Answer (score 0):

As a workorund you can disable innodb persistent stats.
It is fixed on 5.7.18.

```
[mysqld]
innodb-stats-persistent=0
innodb-stats-transient-sample-pages=20
innodb-stats-auto-recalc=0
```